# Visual Studio 2019: Peek definition with combination of mouse and keyboard click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

By default, **Peek Definition** is performed if you click `Alt`+`F12` in VS 2019.  If you use mouse click + `Ctrl` then **Go to Definition** is performed.
Is there also an option to use the combination of mouse click and a keystroke to perform **Peek Definition**?

Comment: Does two clicks count? (Peek definition is in the context menu.)

Comment: @Richard, ok let me get this straight. There is a reason why MS provides `Ctrl`+`Click` for **Go to Definition** although the same feature is also available in the context menu. Using keystroke with just one click has a better UX for many users.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set an option first (documented below).

So..**.CTRL+Click** will go to the definition.
You can make it open a Peek window by changing an option.

**Click Tools->Options**
Under **Text Editor->General**
Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition (should be checked)
Check the **Open definition in peek view**

Now Ctrl+Click will open a peek window.

You could also just right click on it and Peek Definition.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I don't want to remove the feature **Go to Definition**. I was looking for an option to have the same feature for **Peek Definition** in addition to have **Go to Definition** with Mouse and Keystroke

Comment: this works on VS2019 too, as well as even after installing ProductivityPowerTools extensions.

Comment: @Code Pope Belated, but the Peek view itself will let you jump to the definition by double-clicking on a code location in the peek.

Comment: Though it would be nice to just have two different shortcuts, I agree.